# Menu Item click, Fragments show

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have been searching for this but was not able to implement it. My problem is i have two **menu** in the toolbar **`action_settings`** and **`repeat_entry`** ,when i click action_settings fragment **category settings** should show and when i click `repeat_entry` **Repeat entry** Fragment should show

Here is my **menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/repeat_entry" android:title="Repeat Entry"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

heres my onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected **MainActivity.java**

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menu.removeItem(R.id.action_search);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
        }


 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        Fragment fr = null;
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            selectTabToShow(String.valueOf(R.id.action_search));
            CategorySettings fragemnt = (CategorySettings) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.categorySettings);
            fr = new CategorySettings();

        }else if(id == R.id.repeat_entry){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ssdf sdf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fr = new RepeatEntry();
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.categorySettings,fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Heres a part of my **activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/category_cont"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <fragment
                android:name="me2.nakame.hp.moneytracer.CategorySettings"
                android:id="@+id/categorySettings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

this is my fragment RepeatEntry and CategorySettings is almost alike

```
public class RepeatEntry extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat_entry,container,false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

my problem is only CategorySettings is showing

Comment: 'Fragment should show' that is your desired behavior, now mention what problem you are facing? Are your fragments not showing? any crash?

Comment: Try replacing <fragment> with <FrameLayout>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved my problem by just removing the **`<fragment>` and use .replace method for fragment transaction**

This is the updated part of the **activity_main.xml** where i remove the fragment

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/category_cont"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

This is now the update method of  `onOptionsItemSelected` under my main activity

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();


            Fragment fragment = null;
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                fragment = new CategorySettings();
            }else if(id == R.id.repeat_entry){
                fragment = new RepeatEntry();

            }

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.category_cont,fragment);
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,android.R.animator.fade_out);
            ft.commit();

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```